# Play several audio clips sequentially

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game built upon unity, which can be played for longer than 3-5 minutes. So, I want a set of songs(atleast 2) that can be played one after another.

I know how to set one particular audio source to the main camera of the scene and set it on loop; but that would be monotonous, so I'd like to know how to add a set of songs to a particular scene and play them in a sequential fashion?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to add a set of songs to a particular scene and play them in a
>   sequential fashion

It's really easy. Use one `AudioSource` only. Use AudioClip to hold the audios to play. If possible, use `AudioClip` array.

**1**.Use `for` loops to loop through the `AudioClip` array.

**2**.In each loop, assign the current `AudioClip` from the loop to the `AudioSource.clip` variable.

**3**.Call `AudioSource.Play();` after that to play the audio.

**4**.Use while loop to wait for the current `AudioClip` to finish playing with `while (AudioSource.isPlaying){ yield return null;}`

**5**.Go back to **#2**.

```
public AudioSource adSource;
public AudioClip[] adClips;

IEnumerator playAudioSequentially()
{
    yield return null;

    //1.Loop through each AudioClip
    for (int i = 0; i < adClips.Length; i++)
    {
        //2.Assign current AudioClip to audiosource
        adSource.clip = adClips[i];

        //3.Play Audio
        adSource.Play();

        //4.Wait for it to finish playing
        while (adSource.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //5. Go back to #2 and play the next audio in the adClips array
    }
}
```

To start it, just call `StartCoroutine(playAudioSequentially());`.

Comment: how to add multiple songs to audio clip within one audio source? I am able to just select one song..

Comment: For one song in a loop there is no code needed. Just drag the audio to the AudioClip slot of the AudioSource then enable Loop and Play On Awake. That's it but you are doing something different. You need a code to do that. Use the solution I provided above and load as many audios as you want to the adClips slot from the Editor.

Comment: How to play the list only once then stop and don't loop the list?

Comment: This will play the list and stop after the last song. Not sure if this is the desired outcome.